# Does an element with a specific innerHTML exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I have a list of span elemets with values:

```
    <span>Example1</span>
    <span>Example2</span>
    <span>Example3</span>
    <span>Example4</span>
    <span>Example5</span>
```

How would I be able to check if there is a span with for example "Example4" inside?

I've tried the following yet with no result:

```
    if($('span').textContent = value){
     console.log('exists');
    }

    if($('span').html(value){}
    if($('span').html(value).length > 0){}
```

but they always return true..

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: You want to check for element contains string or substring or element's content to match exactly string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
if ( $('span:contains("Example4")').length > 0 ) { ... }
```

However this approach [will fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266540/does-an-element-with-a-specific-innerhtml-exist/23266565#comment35606184_23266565) if there are `<span>` elements with text like `"Example 40"`. For strict comparison you may use trick with a `.filter` method:

```
if ( $('span').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($.text(this)) === 'Example4';
}).length > 0 ) { ... }
```

Comment: Just hope there isn't a span with the text `Example41` etc.. ;)

Comment: @Archer Yeah, that's the main drawback of this approach ;)

Comment: I did +1 because it's probably not going to happen.  I would have gone with a map or filter instead.  It may take a hundredth of a second longer though :D

Comment: Thanks @VisioN that's even better! :o

Answer (score 0):

The Array method [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (IE9+) returns true if any member matches the given condition:

```
var matched = $('span').toArray().some(function(node) {
  return node.innerHTML == 'Example4';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test it first and use it to fit your code block.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createElement123(){
            if ( $('span:contains("Example4")').length > 0 ) {
                alert('Exists');
            } else {
                alert('Not Exists');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="createElement123()" value="Check Text Exists"/>
    <span>Example1</span>
    <span>Example2</span>
    <span>Example3</span>
    <span>Example4</span>
    <span>Example5</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope that it will help you to solve your problem.